# Create a minor mode only for prog-mode major modes

Tags: minor-mode, prog-mode

I am working on a minor-mode and I'd like it to be active only for major modes derived from prog-mode.

So far I know that the macro `define-minor-mode` takes a argument `:global` to decide whether or not the mode should be global.  But this is too general.

And I'd like not requiring the user to set-up the mode itself with a hook à la:
`(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook (lambda () (my-minor-mode t)))`

Thanks

Comment: This can be shortened to `(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'my-minor-mode)` thanks to `define-minor-mode`.

Comment: "I'd like not requiring the user to set-up the mode itself with a hook" just sounds silly, because that's precisely how one *expects* to do this in Emacs. Any users who aren't already familiar with that pattern need to *become* familiar with it, because it's standard practice. Which perceived problem are you trying to circumvent here?

Comment: If you are determined to not do that, then it sounds like you should define an additional *globalized* minor mode, such that the (new) global mode controls your (existing) buffer-local minor mode, and switches it on in a buffer if `(derived-mode-p 'prog-mode)`. See `define-globalized-minor-mode`